# Creating Route 53 records for S3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to create a CI/CD build plan where static files are deployed to S3 and Route 53 updates DNS records per S3 bucket.

Basically I'm looking for some place to start. Having Route 53 dynamically update when a new S3 bucket is created is the main hurdle I'm trying to tackle right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trigger for creation of an S3 bucket, that i know of. So the script that creates the bucket will need to trigger the Route53 update as well.

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you can deploy to the same bucket, and then with S3 events, [trigger a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) to clean out the Cloudfront cache, and hence serve the updated static files.

You could also setup a [periodic Cloudwatch trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html), to trigger a Lambda script that updates Route53 to point to an appropriate bucket every few minutes.

Comment: This is great. It gives me somewhere to start. Thank you!